# How can I untangle multiple Maybes nested at different levels?

Tags: haskell

Working with `Maybe` seems really difficult in Haskell. I was able to implement the function I need after many frustrating compile errors, but it's still completely disorganized and I don't know how else can I improve it.

I need to:

- extract multiple nested `... Maybe`s into one, final `Maybe ...`
- Do `a -> b -> IO ()` with `Just a` and `Just b` or nothing (*)

Here is example with `IO` part removed. I need `a -> b -> IO ()`, not `(a,b) -> IO ()` later but I couldn't figure out how to pass both arguments otherwise (I can `mapM_` with one argument only).

```
import Network.URI

type URL = String
type Prefix = String

fubar :: String -> Maybe (Prefix, URL)
fubar url = case parseURI url of
    Just u -> (flip (,) $ url)
               <$> (fmap ((uriScheme u ++) "//" ++ ) ((uriRegName <$> uriAuthority u)))
    _ -> Nothing
```

Result:

```
> fubar "https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#mapM"
Just ("https://hackage.haskell.org"
     ,"https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#mapM"
     )
```

(*) printing what failed to parse wrong would be nice

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is pretty simple written with `do` notation:

```
fubar :: String -> Maybe (Prefix, URL)
fubar url = do
  u <- parseURI url
  scheme <- uriScheme u
  authority <- uriAuthority u
  return (scheme ++ "//" ++ uriRegName authority, url)
```

Monads in general (and Maybe in particular) are all about combining `m (m a)` into `m a`. Each `<-` binding is an alternate syntax for a call to `>>=`, the operator responsible for aborting if it sees a Nothing, and otherwise unwrapping the Just for you.

Answer (score 5):

First note that you're just stacking multiple `fmap`s there, with `α <$> (fmap β (γ <$> uriAuthority u))`. This can (functor laws!) be rewritten `α . β . γ <$> uriAuthority u`, i.e.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

   ...
    Just u -> (,url) . ((uriScheme u++"//") ++ ) . uriRegName <$> uriAuthority u
```

It might be better for legibility to actually keep the layers separate, but then you should also give them names as amalloy suggests.

Further, more strongly:

> Extract multiple nested `M` into one, final `M`

Well, sounds like monads, doesn't it?

```
fubar url = do
   u <- parseURI url
   (,url) . ((uriScheme u++"//") ++ ) . uriRegName <$> uriAuthority u
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely clear on precisely what you're asking, but I'll do my best to answer the questions you have presented.

To extract multiple nested `Maybe`s into a single final `Maybe` is taken care of by `Maybe`'s monad-nature (also applicative-nature).  How specifically to do it depends on how they are nested.

Simplest example:

```
Control.Monad.join :: (Monad m) => m (m a) -> m a
-- thus 
Control.Monad.join :: Maybe (Maybe a) -> Maybe a
```

A tuple:

```
squishTuple :: (Maybe a, Maybe b) -> Maybe (a,b)
squishTuple (ma, mb) = do  -- do in Maybe monad
    a <- ma
    b <- mb
    return (a,b)

-- or
squishTuple (ma, mb) = liftA2 (,) ma mb
```

A list:

```
sequenceA :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => t (f a) -> f (t a)
-- thus
sequenceA :: [Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]
-- (where t = [], f = Maybe)
```

Other structures can be flattened by composing these and following the types.  For example:

```
flattenComplexThing :: (Maybe a, [Maybe (Maybe b)]) -> Maybe (a, [b])
flattenComplexThing (ma, mbs) = do
    a <- ma
    bs <- (join . fmap sequenceA . sequenceA) mbs
    return (a, bs)
```

That `join . fmap sequenceA . sequenceA` line is a bit complex, and it takes some getting used to to know how to construct things like this.  My brain works in a very type-directed way (read the composition right-to-left):

```
[Maybe (Maybe b)]
      |
   sequenceA :: [Maybe _] -> Maybe [_]
      ↓
Maybe [Maybe b]
      |
    -- sequenceA :: [Maybe b] -> Maybe [b]
    -- fmap f  makes the function f work "inside" the Maybe, so
   fmap sequenceA :: Maybe [Maybe b] -> Maybe (Maybe [b])
      ↓
Maybe (Maybe [b])
      |
   join :: Maybe (Maybe _) -> Maybe _
      ↓
Maybe [b]
```

---

As for the second question, how to do an `a -> b -> IO ()` when you have `Maybe a` and `Maybe b`, presuming you don't want to do the action at all in the case that either one is `Nothing`, you just do some gymnastics:

```
conditional :: (a -> IO ()) -> Maybe a -> IO ()
conditional = maybe (return ())

conditional2 :: (a -> b -> IO ()) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b -> IO ()
conditional2 f ma mb = conditional (uncurry f) (liftA2 (,) ma mb)
```

Again I found `conditional2` in a mainly type-directed way in my mind.

It takes some time to develop your type gymnastics, but then it starts to get really fun.  To make code like this readable, it's important to use helper functions, e.g. `conditional` above, and name them well (which is arguable about `conditional` :-).  You'll gradually get familiar with the standard library's helpers.  There's no magic bullet here, you just have to get used to it -- it's a language.  Work with it, strive for clarity, if something is too ugly try your best to make it prettier.  And ask more specific questions :-)